# How to implement graphical view of data inside an app or a webapp?

Tags: android, ios, web-applications

I've seen this on youtube http://youtu.be/vHuDvxkwzpI.
I need to replicate something like this inside an app on ios or inside a website, that can be consulted on mobile devices or put into a webapp schema. 
In other words, I need to implement this and allow the user to see it on his cell phone or tablet.
Some ideas?

Comment: For iOs you can do it easily, with `view animation's`

Comment: "Easily" is a big word :D I'm a beginner! Where do i can start from?

Comment: check `http://code4app.net/` category animation there are examples